# print without main function in java

Tags: java

I keep getting this question asked by my friends

Write a program to **print "Hello,World" without using main() function** in java

So my question is:

**Is it really possible to write and compile a program without main() without exception**.?

Comment: I have to ask why? - What would that prove, apart from the fact that you can do things the hard and unconventional way - which is pointless?

Comment: i guess to know more ways and concepts

Comment: Suppose, but I still seams a strange question. There are plenty of other ways to prove such things that actually make sense, and are useful etc! Anyway, interesting question though...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public class Test {
    static {
        System.out.println("Hello,World");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Will print `Hello,World`, with a pre-1.7 Java VM. Oracle JDK 1.7 checks for a `main` before initializing the class.

The [JLS Execution part 12.1.4](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#12.1.4) seems to indicate that the JVM *will* attempt to run a `main` method, but only after initializers have run. This appears to be interpreted differently in Java 1.7.

Special thanks to [Ted Hopp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535871/ted-hopp) for the `System.exit(0)` line.

Comment: can you print without exception?

Comment: You can avoid the exception by adding a call to `System.exit(0);` after the `println`.

Comment: That won't work because you need class with main() in order to start the JVM

Comment: The JVM first loads the class, then looks for its main method, and throws an exception. But on loading the class, the static block is executed

Comment: @OpDeCirkel: try it, and see the link to the JLS I posted.

Comment: This doesn't work in Eclipse or from command line, for me anyways.

Comment: @Mat Java Hotspot Client VM 21.2-b02

Comment: @Jeffrey: interesting - Works in Java 1.6, but 1.7 does some extra checking - I wasn't aware of that, and hadn't read the spec that way. Updated my answer, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

You can run java web project on a server(Tomcat for instance).
That project can use servlet for printing 'Hello World'

Comment: How it isn't related? When you deploy a servlet it will print HelloWorld without a main method. The container itslef has the main method of course, but your reaction is a bit odd

Comment: sorry, i had no idea, i was just thinking in normal programming, my fault

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: no.

Mat showed a wonderful example of how you can do something close to it, but you'll get an exception.

Every java program needs a main method, even though it may be hidden in some ways. For example, when you write a Servlet, you don't write a main method, but it still exists in the servlet container's code.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to do it

```
public class WithoutMain {

    static {
        System.err.println("Hello World");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

When running the JVM will start with creating the class, and when doing that the class will first print Hello World and after that exit the JVM (with *System.exit(0);*) so the JVM will never get to the point where it sees that a *main* method is missing.

Answer (score -1):

No, of course you can write and compile a program without main(), but u can't run it.
To run a program main is compulsory.